# Independent platform hash of a C++ data structure

Tags: c++, boost, hash, stl, hashmap

I would like to evaluate a hash for a C++ data-structure, containing mainly `double`, and `std::string`. Boost proposes some functions to do so, with [hash](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/doc/html/hash/reference.html#header.boost.functional.hash_hpp) and [sha1](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/boost/uuid/sha1.hpp).

`Boost hash` is known to be [platform dependent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17426493/get-32-bit-hash-value-from-boosthash), since it returns a `std::size_t`. However, its API is very handy, thanks to its extensions that deal with `stl` containers.

For example, `Boost hash` allows to declare such a hash

```
#include <boost/functional/hash.hpp>
boost::hash<MyType> hash;
std::size_t seed = hash(MyType());
```

I would like to benefit from the same API using boost SHA1.
Is there a higher API level for `SHA1`, than the `process_bytes` method?

Comment: Cryptographic hashes like SHA-1 fundamentally work on a stream of bytes. So if you want to use one of those, the problem reduces to that of serializing your data structure in a platform-independent format. See if [Boost Serialization](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/serialization/) helps.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik I've demo-ed just that here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30097385/hash-an-arbitrary-precision-value-boostmultiprecisioncpp-int/30111778#30111778